# Schedule event for every second in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, events, scheduled-tasks

I want to send an email every second using my custom plugin for testing purpose. I have written the code to schedule this event but i m not getting emails. I am not sure if I have scheduled it correctly, but apparently everything seems fine. here is my code, I have written this code in plugin.

```
<?php


register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');

function isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval( $schedules ) {

$schedules['every_second'] = array(
    'interval'  => 1,
    'display'   => __( 'Every second', 'textdomain' )
);

return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval' );

function my_activation() {
if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'everysecond', 'my_event');
}
}

add_action('my_event', 'do_this');

function do_this() {
    mail('haris.4090@gmail.com','Testing','testing email from plugin');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct typo noticed by Felipe Elia in his answer.

But even in this case it wouldn't work.

1. WP cron a activates when somebody is visiting your site. At WordPress init process, cron checks if there are any scheduled events, which execution time is already over and fires such events.

So, if your site is visited several times per second, it can work, but do you actually have so many visitors?

In practice, email will be sent once per visit (let say 100 visits per day = 100 emails per day).

2. Even if you have multiple visits per second, emails will be sent not every second, because WordPress initialization time is often longer.

Let say event is scheduled. First visit after 1 sec from this time will trigger event. Let us assume init time is 1.5 sec. So, you will have a new email after 2.5 sec from the first one. And next event will be fired then. So, the third email you will have in 5 seconds from the first, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like just a typo. This

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'everysecond', 'my_event');
```

should be

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'every_second', 'my_event');
```

as written in `$schedules['every_second']`